# Saving a value from select option to database

Tags: php

So i am trying to insert some data in my database, unfortunatly it doesn't work as i hoped. 
This is my index.php file here i made a little piece of php code to get the select options from my database(this works fine). But now i want people to select from the options in my database and store the selected option in another db table.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT event_naam FROM events";

$result2 = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);

$options = "";

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $options = $options."<option>$row2[0]</option>";
}
?>
<form class="inschrijven" method="POST" action="includes/inscscript.php">
    <select name="iselect">
        <?php echo $options;?>
    </select><br><br>
    <span>Uw Naam: </span><input type="text" name="inaam" placeholder="Naam"><br>
    <span>Leeftijd: </span><input type="number" name="leeftijd"><br>
    <span>Aantal Personen:</span><input type="number" name="personen"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="inschrijven" value="Inschrijven!">
</form>
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't do anything it also doesn't give an error.

```
require_once 'connectie.php'; //Connection to Database File

$sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijven (inschrijf_event, inschrijf_naam, inschrijf_leeftijd, inschrijf_personen) VALUES 
('".$_POST['iselect']."','".$_POST['inaam']."','".$_POST['leeftijd']."','".$_POST['personen']."')";

if ($dbconn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 header( "Location: ../index.php" );
} else {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $dbconn->error."');</script>";
}

$dbconn->close();
```

This is my inscscript.php file

I tried searching for similair qeustions but couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: Use $options = $options."<option value='$row2[0]'>$row2[0]</option>";  Give value to option

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT event_naam FROM events";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query)
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  while($rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result)){
echo "<option value='".$rowcount['event_naam']."'>".$rowcount['event_naam']."</option>
}
```

Include this php file to your html between select opend and closing tags